# Wine - YnHub port problem

Tags: wine

I host a hub using Ynhub on Windows with port 10.22.24.228:511. I want to continue the hub on Ubuntu.

I couldn't find Ynhub software for Linux, so I tried opening it with Wine. But hosting ports more than 1023 only works.

It shows up this error if I tried to host with port 511:

```
Failed to start listening on port 511, port may be inuse
```

and same errors respectively for all ports less than 1024.

Can I do anything to host my hub (using Ynhub) with 511 port? Otherwise I will have to lose all my users. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with Wine and YnHub for a while now.

Since you have linux, why don't you use [Verlihub](http://www.verlihub-project.org/) or [PtokaX](http://www.ptokax.org/) instead? They are more robust and of course, YnHub has many connection problems even on Windows (not mentioning MANY security issues).

**EDIT:** Or other solution, you must create Virtual Machine with Windows installed and then use YnHub on Windows within virtual OS.

**Edit:** You may also use port forwarding from a your router to help you. Just create YnHub port to one that is higher than 1023 and then use port forwarding from outside port 511 to your internal YnHub port.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am having problem installing Verlihub :(
I don't have experience with terminal much.I was following the instructions given . I get this error :
"checking for C++ compiler default output file name... configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables" when I type configure in verlihub folder

Comment: You need to install C/C++ compiler. to do so you may use this terminal command: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. :) Then try installation again.

Comment: Also, there are few tutorials on google that tells you how to install Verlihub. This is [example](http://ubuntu-for-humans.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-install-verlihub-on-ubuntu.html]) tutorial.

Comment: PS, I just found out that Ubuntu won't let you use ports under 1024 unless it runs in root privileges... Therefore upper port should have worked. https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=15239